# how to sync last modified files from folders on linux

Tags: linux, synchronization, overriding, directory, rsync

I am trying to sync two folders, both have last modified files.
I used `rsyn -av`, but the files in the second folder were overridden by the first. How can I sync them without replacing the last modified files regardless of the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use the --update (-u) flag, this option allows you to rsync and skip files that are new in the destination directory. As suggested from the man page